# Need alternative of elastic search in php and dont want to purchase another server

Tags: php, ajax, elasticsearch

I need alternative of elastic search in php and I do not want to purchase another server. I am working on project that require auto suggest from hug data. For that elastic search was proper. But I dont want to purchase any other server.

Please suggest me alternative of elastic search or any solution for elastic search. I dont want to use simple ajax call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already had this working with Elasticsearch, the obvious solution you are looking for is the open-source version of Elasticsearch. Prepare the Elasticsearch index on some other node and publish the resulting index to the website. This way, you don't have the computational overhead of indexing on the single-node instance of Elasticsearch.

If the data set is not too large, there are some pure Javascript options for autocompletion - with or without pre-loading.

The hug data is probably huge data :-) Why would you need an extra server? Are you talking about a subscription from Elastic?

Answer (score 1):

Below I gave 2 alternates for elastic search. you can install it  in your server and use their API to integrate to PHP

1) [Spinxsearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

2) [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)